# Malinois in an appartment with enough exercise: Feasible?

Tags: dogs, exercise, breeds

How feasible is it to have a Malinois in an apartment if given enough exercise?

I am joking that my dog will be "exercise equipment" - I think that an hour of biking in the morning plus some training/free play in the evening would be about right. He probably will also have a second dog to keep him company in during the day :)

Can this work out? Or am I setting myself up for failure and I should get a German Shepherd instead? (I had German Shepherds before. I am tired of wondering about problems with the hips, especially with lots of exercise.)

Comment: you're going to have to dedicate like 6 hrs a day to letting it exercise outside.

Answer (score 1):

If you can handle German Shepherds in your apartment, you can handle [Malinois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malinois_dog).

That being said, if the dog is not some kind of [inbred couch potato](https://www.cesarsway.com/about-dogs/breeds/have-we-overbred-bulldogs), they will **NEED** the exercise. Dogs are a big commitment in time, if not money.

---

As for an anecdote, the one Malinois I have run into, that dog did not stop playing fetch or any other game. The whole day long. Think puppy energy levels. Think border collie energy. With focus. Select yours carefully for the energy level you think you can handle.

Comment: I am getting the Malinois as an exercise partner.

Comment: Then please get your exercise routine going for at least 2 months before getting a dog. I have seen exercises last weeks if months. Dogs last years. A dog is not the solution to your exercise.

Comment: Milinois tend to need a good amount more excerise that a german shepherd..

Comment: The exercise routine was already in place with two dogs that my ex stole (German Shepherd, Presa Canario). I am switching now from "long walks with the dogs" to "running and biking" because long walks by myself are horribly depressing. By the time lawyers do their thing and I figure out that my ex has already gotten rid of the dogs the exercise routine will be firmly in place.

Comment: @Daniel How much exercise would a malinios need? This is really the root of the question?

Comment: @Censoredtoprotecttheguilty im no expert at all by any means, but from what i have read around , they need A LOT of exercise, like they dont stop all day kind of exercise..

Comment: @Daniel What you are telling me is that if I take them on a fast bike ride in the morning for an hour, they won't be OK for the rest of the day? A guy on a bike can  make the dogs run as fast as required, I don't think there are many dogs that can keep up with a bike for an hour (And some mental exercise at night - training, playing etc)

Comment: @Censoredtoprotecttheguilty Im not telling you anything just what i read, i am not qualified to tell you, i never owned a Malinois..but look around in the internet, im sure you will find forums

Comment: @Censoredtoprotecttheguilty the size of your apartment shouldn't be much of a concern since it should be the place of rest an relaxation. Don't play inside. The energylevel of a Malinois is generally high but the key factor is determined by the character of the dog, you might end up with a lacy dog in a high energy dog costume. Malinois are very smart dogs, therefor mental training over physically might be the key here, since it can drain more energy in shorter time. You set the standards for the amount of exercise your dog needs, don't overshoot in the beginning if you can't keep the level.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you have a forest nearby where you can have the dog run free. Keep in mind that these dogs are ready to bite, protect, sniff and put their life on the line - for a toy. This means they are sharp, smart, do not tolerate nonsense from you as a handler and require a lot of time. 4-5 hours per day is ok. This does include going out to defecate, but 1-2 two-hour sessions of training every day is what it takes to get the dog tired.

You have to be able to get the dog tired - then it sleeps and you can do other things. It does not matter as much if it is an apartment, a farm, or a cardboard box - as long as you can get the dog completely exhausted every single day, then you are doing your part of the deal and everything will be fine. Of course the benefit of a farm is that you can let the environment do the work - in an apartment YOU have to take the dog out and do the work.